# Aframe dynamic-body's fall through a collada static-body floor

Tags: javascript, game-physics, aframe

Using aframe and the aframe-physics-system I've noticed an issue where "dynamic-body's" are falling through a simple Collada based "static-body".

All the dynamic-body's should be bouncing on the blue floor, however in my case all but the sphere objects fall THROUGH the floor. I'm not sure why.

Here is the jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/9z9e1jtk/

```
<a-scene fog="type: linear; color: #FFEBDE; far:195" >
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="ground" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/7ammer/testfiles/master/aframe-ground-physics/floor.dae"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

     <a-entity camera
        universal-controls
        jump-ability
        kinematic-body
        position="0 2 10">
    </a-entity>

    <a-box color="red"
        dynamic-body
        position="0 10 0"
        height="4"></a-box>

    <a-cylinder color="#ddb424"
       position="-5 10 0"
       dynamic-body></a-cylinder>

    <a-sphere color="#ddb424"
       position="5 5 0"
       dynamic-body></a-sphere>

    <a-entity static-body collada-model="#ground"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: I posted an issue here: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/issues/9 and it seems that Collada models are only partially supported by Cannon.js. See the link for more details.

Comment: I posted the answer to your question. Please mark as right if you are still active. :)

Answer (score 1):

Collada is not longer supported in Aframe Version 0.9.0 and higher. There is support implemented in aframe-extras v.6.0.0 and higher for those who need it. Reference: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3793

You can use gltf or aframe entities as your ground.

An example:

```
<a-entity id="ground" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 500; width: 500" material=" opacity:0.0" position="0 0 0" static-body rotation="90 0 0"></a-entity>
```

Important is, that you use `collision-filter`. This means you declare a group for your entity and every entity it should collide with. Do this with `group:name` and `collidesWith: groupname`. If you want to make it easy, you can just declare one group for every item that should be able to collide. So you set the groupname to group 1 and let it collide with group 1.

It looks then like this:

```
<a-entity id="ground" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 500; width: 500" material=" opacity:0.0" position="0 0 0" static-body rotation="90 0 0" 
        collision-filter="group: group1; collidesWith: group1"></a-entity>
```

Your other entities, like cubes or gltf Models need to get the same tag.

```
<a-box collision-filter="group: group1; collidesWith: group1"> </a-box>
```

To make it even easier, just declare a a-mixin meta-tag and pass it to every item that should get the collision function:

```
<a-mixin id="collision" dynamic-body collision-filter="group: group1; collidesWith: group1"></a-mixin>

<a-box mixin="collision"></a-box>

<a-entity id="ground" geometry="primitive: plane; height: 500; width: 500" material=" opacity:0.0" position="0 0 0" static-body rotation="90 0 0" 
            mixin="collision"></a-entity>
```

With a gltf-model do the same (inline example):

```
<a-entity dynamic-body gltf-model="url(url/to/gltfmodel.gltf)" mixin="collision"></a-entity>
```

References: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm 2 years late, but try applying a secondary plane inside the sphere to act as a better physics collider. I'd make the plane bigger than the sphere and then set the opacity to 0%.